# Forum vB plugin not working

Tags: php, plugins, hook, forum, vbulletin

So I made a plugin/hook

```
<?php
ob_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/delta/pack_files/other/login.php";
$loginphpp = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

I enabled hooks/plugins in the settings, and i set this plugin to be at global_start

the folder directory is correct and I called this with $loginphpp, but nothing shows.

Any ideas why?

Comment: What's the complaint here?  That $loginphpp has nothing in it?

Comment: That's a bad way to implement templates in VB. Use VBulletin templates system. It is powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised how stupid I've been

With vBulletin plugins, you don't include

so it'd just be:

```
ob_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/delta/pack_files/other/login.php";
$loginphpp = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

They really should write that somewhere :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with vBulletin plugins, but, `ob_end_clean()` will clear the output buffer and cause nothing to be sent out to the browser. What about removing all your output buffering control:

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/delta/pack_files/other/login.php');
?>
```